# Batch change creation dates based on file names

Tags: terminal, unix, file, macos

I have files that are named like "12. 2017-04-11 063118.jpg", and "123. 2016-09-05 115236.jpg". The number to the left of the "." counts up like an index from 1 to 1400.

How can I set the creation date and time according to how it is specified in the file name for all 1400 files I have in the folder. I know the command touch -t changes the creation date, but I do not know how to extract the date/time information from the file name and put this into a command so this is done automatically for all files.

I know from another thread that the below should work. but i don't know how to tweak the text conversion to correctly apply to my file naming convention.

```
for f in *; do
    t=$(echo $f | sed -E 's/([A-z]*-)|([ ,;])|(\..*)//g' | sed -E 's/(.*)(..)/\1.\2/')
    touch -t $t "$f"
done
```

The above code works if my file naming convention is like "clip-2014-01-31 18;50;15.mp4", however, I have a different format: "12. 2017-04-11 063118.jpg", and "123. 2016-09-05 115236.jpg". Does anyone know how to tweak the `sed` function command to process the conversion into the correct format for touch?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bash parameter expansion will work:

```
for f in *; do
    t="${f#* }"
    t="${t%%.*}"
    t="${t:0:4}${t:5:2}${t:8:2}${t:11:2}${t:13:2}.${t:15:2}"
    touch -t $t "$f"
done
```

- `t="${f#* }"` strips off the part before  (< the first space)
- `t="${t%%.*}"` strips off the part after `.`
- `t="${t:0:4}${t:5:2}${t:8:2}${t:11:2}${t:13:2}.${t:15:2}"` formats the content of the date variable (t) for touch which requires the following format: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS].

And as one-liner:

```
for f in *; do t="${f#* }"; t="${t%%.*}"; t="${t:0:4}${t:5:2}${t:8:2}${t:11:2}${t:13:2}.${t:15:2}"; touch -t $t "$f"; done
```

Comment: The `bare *`(glob) will list every file system object in the directory. Do you think that using `*.jpg` would be a better choice?

Comment: @fd0 The solution will only work for the given format `something_without_spaces YYYY[.|-|:]MM[.|-|:]DD hhmmSS.someextension`. It won't change the creation date if the required format CCYYMMDDhhmm.SS is wrong though (e.g. contains letters or if the dot is missing).

Answer (score 3):

Since you asked how you could tweak what you already had, you'd change the capture groups in the first occurrence of `sed` to match the new pattern, while leaving the second `sed` as is. Also double quote the `$f` in `echo "$f" |`.

Note however, I've eliminated the use of the pipe and second occurrence of `sed`, `| sed ...`, by use of the `-e` option, which appends the editing commands into a list of commands.

```
for f in *; do
    t=$(echo "$f" | sed -E -e 's/(.*\. )|([-])|([ ])|(\..*)//g' -e 's/(.*)(..)/\1.\2/')
    touch -t $t "$f"
done
```

Here it is tweaked as a one-liner:

```
for f in *; do t=$(echo "$f" | sed -E -e 's/(.*\. )|([-])|([ ])|(\..*)//g' -e 's/(.*)(..)/\1.\2/'); touch -t $t "$f"; done
```

Here's an explication of the capture groups in the first `sed` editing command:

[image]

Which leaves you with `20160905115236` and when processed by the second `sed` editing command, it becomes `201609051152.36` as `(.*)(..)` breaks it down to two capture groups, the second containing the last two characters and the first containing everything else. The `.` gets placed in the substitution portion having back-referenced `/\1.\2/` both capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

If the files contain exit tags, the free 'exiftool' can change the file name according to values within the file.  Installing it also installs a detailed man page.

http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

I have used this tool to not only change file names, but to write HTML snippets to show the files on a web page.

Comment: OK, my bad.  Reading it again, I see you want to change the file dates, not the name.  It may be that exiftool can do that.  My MAC is not working, so I can't read the man page.